# dynamically generating html with jade

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, pug

I am trying to get a stream of data updating jade in realtime. 
I was told I should use socket.io and I managed to get it connected, but I can't access it's values in the template.

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title= title
    script(src='components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js')
    script(type='text/javascript' src='https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.0.6.js')
    script(type='text/javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jade/1.11.0/jade.min.js')
    script(type='text/javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jade/1.11.0/runtime.min.js')
    script.
      var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8898/');
        socket.on('news', function (data) {
          console.log("jade connected to socket.io")
          console.log(data);
          var photo = data.hello.data[0].images.original.url; 
          console.log(photo);
      });
  body
  block content
    img(src=photo) // results in empty img tag
    img(src={photo}) // results in <img src="[object Object]">
    img(src=#{photo}) // results in undefined
```

Console output:
jade connected to socket.io

(index):4 Object {hello: Object, photo: "http://media1.com/media/26FPMmPhlkKjHFXW/file.jpg"}
(index):6 http://media1.com/media/26FPMmPhlkKjHFXW/file.jpg

I will be happy to see jade picking up the image, meaning that I could finally get data from the backend. 
I will still need to go through the array in the data object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your setup, the Jade template is rendered just once (server-side, when a request is handled).

To perform dynamic updates, you need at least two things:

- some sort of communication channel with the server; you're using `socket.io` for this, which is a good choice;
- code that will manipulate the DOM to change the appearance of the page; you're not doing this yet.

Given your code, you can try this:

```
script.
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8898/');
  socket.on('news', function (data) {
    var photo = data.hello.data[0].images.original.url;
    document.getElementById('photo').src = photo;
  });
body
  block content
    img#photo(src='placeholder.jpg')
```

Comment: It works, but will it update the jade template when there is new data? How should I iterate over the array dynamically in jade?

Comment: @staminna if the data is coming in over a `socket.io` channel, it means that you need to iterate over the data in the browser, so you would need some sort of client-side solution to handle it. If you don't necessarily need the real time aspect, you can pass a variable to `res.render()` that holds the array, and you can use Jade constructs like `each` to iterate over the data.

Comment: I really need the real time aspect @robertklep .

Comment: Perhaps with the insertAdjacentHTML() method or could there be a specific jade system for this?

Comment: 403 is "forbidden", so the server is not allowing your requests for some reason (what that reason is I can't say).